# How to retrieve HttpResponseMessage content headers for a live media stream (in a windows store app using c#)

Tags: c#, httpresponse, windows-8.1, shoutcast

I am making an online radio radio app for Windows 8.1 and wanted to communicate with `shoutcast` servers using the new `Windows.Web.Http API` (in order to send custom HTTP headers to get metadata from the live media stream).

The response headers are empty, and I need to read the content headers before starting to read the stream data.

This is the code I tried to use:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Url);
var baseFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
ShoutcastHttpFilter filter = new ShoutcastHttpFilter(baseFilter);
var HClient = new HttpClient(filter);
HttpResponseMessage response = await HClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

Task streaming = null;
Stream stream = null;
stream = response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync().GetResults().AsStreamForRead();

string str = response.Content.Headers["Icy-MetaInt"];
```

When I run/debug the code, the content appears as "unbuffered" and has no headers.
How can I get the content headers and the stream?

This the code I used in ShoutcastHttpFilter:

```
request.Headers.Clear();
request.Headers.Add("Icy-MetaData", "1");
request.Headers["User-Agent"] = "VLC media player";
request.Headers["Connection"] = "Close";
HttpResponseMessage response = await innerFilter.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(cancellationToken, progress);

cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
return response;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the header name does not start with `Content-*`, then the header must be in the response headers.

Do this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
    uri,
    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
string value = response.Headers["Icy-MetaInt"];
```

Comment: I already tried the response headers first, it was empty. "An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: Can you  capture [NetMon](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) traces?

Comment: As well as share the `ShoutcastHttpFilter` source code?

Comment: I used Wireshark to inspect the request and response, the request headers included the custom headers added by ShoutcastHttpFilter, the response had no headers. ShoutcastHttpFilter is extended from IHttpFilter to add the custom headers for Shoutcast servers. I have edited the question to add the code.

Comment: Are you saying that the server don't include headers at all in the response? What is the server URI?

Comment: Sorry, I was filtering the results to show only HTTP protocol, so I only saw the stream data described as _Continuation or non-HTTP traffic_. Now after using the server IP as a filter, I can see the response headers in a TCP segment including the headers I expect, so the question is how can I read these headers? Is there any other class or method supported in windows store apps I can use to send and receive custom headers?

Comment: After searching I found out that shoutcast servers doesn't respond with standard http headers. This is probably why Wireshark classified the response as a TCP segment, but I can't figure out why 'HttpClient' parsed the response as a successful HTTP response without throwing any exceptions or including the custom headers. I suppose I should use a TCP socket instead?